# How to add customizer control via javascript ( wp.customizer.control.add )

Tags: javascript, theme-customizer

I tried to add controls via javascript but it did not show any content.
I tried custom control & core control. My code is almost the same as the code in WordPress core.

Here is my code which is put to the console.

```
testA = wp.customize.control( 'test' );
testA = new wp.customize.controlConstructor.color( 'test', {
  params: {
    label: 'test color',
    section: 'setting_introduction',
    priority: 1,
    active: true,
    type: 'color',
    settings: {
      default: 'test'
    },
  }
} );
wp.customize.control.add( 'test', testA );
```

Where am I doing the mistake ? Please help me.